# How to hide this dropdownmenu on mouseout

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dropdownmenu working as shown on jsfiddle [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/mc7kLc8c/4/)

How can I get the dropdownmenu to be hidden on mouseout? I have added:

```
onmouseout="hidediv()";
```

to the div that contains the drop down menu - but, when you click the link that makes the drop down menu appear - as you move your mouse over the drop down menu it disappears - sometimes. Other times it hangs around as you mouseover the first item in the list, but when you move over the second item in the list - the menu disappears. I don't understand as the mouseout should apply to the whole div.

Comment: Well to whoever downvoted this - I have researched. I have posted code that does not work and have provided a detailed fiddle to replicate the problem. So I have undertaken research effort and the answer posted below proves the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `onmouseout` to `onmouseleave`.

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave):

> Similar to mouseout, [mouseleave] differs in that it doesn't bubble and that it
>   isn't sent until the pointer has moved from its physical space and the
>   one of all its descendants.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/247xdd2n/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two completely independent elements for the menu and the button. Make the menu list `ul#dvMenu` a sub-item of the `ul` under `#navcontainer`, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

BTW, you don't need to have a surrounding div, you can apply all those styles directly to the unordered list. This way you won't leave the context of the element, hence avoiding the unintended hide. Also, bind `onmouseout="hidemenu();"` to the main `<ul>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. They have to be completely independent elements for the menu and the button. Don't ask me why ... the site is an asp.net site with a master page and a user control forming the header that contains the main horizontal list of links. Any sub-menu just won't display. The height of the header div I am using (one my real site, not the jsfiddle) is 90px. A dropdownmenu - even with position:absolute and left set to, say, 200px and top 200px - does not show. So, I need to keep the elements independent as the dropdownmenu code is actually on the master page.

Comment: I have bound onmouseout="hidemenu();" to the main <ul> ... it is more reliable now when mousing over - as you move over the dropdownmenu from the link clicked above - but as soon as you mouseout of the first <li> - the menu disappears.

Comment: In this case I'd recommend just using jQuery if that's at all possible. You can very simply create completely independent behaviors. Elements not showing outside of its parent usually point straight to `overflow: hidden` used on one of the surrounding elements. If you're feeling adventurous, you could try something like `* { overflow: visible; }` and see what happens. ;)

Comment: Any idea why moving off the first <li> in the list causes the mouseout for the <ul> to be triggered?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Adding  onmouseover="showmenu('liHelp');" to each <li> worked ... but is really ugly ... Rick Hitchcock's solution below works. Thanks again.